# Why does "nginx -g daemon off" command work well with "bash -c" but without it gives the error?

Tags: bash, shell, nginx

The command is: `nginx -g daemon off`

My current shell:

```
root@aws:~# echo $0
bash
```

```
root@aws:~# nginx -g daemon off
nginx: invalid option: "off"
root@aws:~# bash -c nginx -g daemon off
root@aws:~#
```

Note:
If I use double quotes across `daemon off` so that it will represent one word it will work: `nginx -g "daemon off;"`

The question arises: If my shell is bash, why then is there an execution difference between not specifying `bash -c` and explicitly specifying it?

Comment: `bash -c nginx -g daemon off` is running just `nginx`, with `-g daemon off` being arguments to *bash*, not `nginx`.

Comment: ^^ this. Try `bash -c 'nginx -g daemon off'` to get the same error.

Comment: @muru but I guess eventually `-g daemon off` should be the argument of `nginx` so why when using `bash -c` it doesn't give this error `nginx: invalid option: "off"`?

Comment: @Hayk no, that's not how it works. Read the answers in the duplicate.